# MidiUnavailableException in Java on Android

Tags: java, android, exception, audio, midi

I am writing a program in Java for android. When calling the getSequencer method, I get a `MidiUnavailableException` exception.
When executing this code :

```
       MidiDevice.Info[] devices = MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo();
    if (devices.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("No MIDI devices found");
    } else {
        for (MidiDevice.Info dev : devices) {
            System.out.println(dev);
        }
    }
```

I got the "No MIDI devices found". I realized that you can solve this problem by installing soundbank at this link:https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/sound-banks.html

But it describes the installation method for Windows. And how to install soundbank for android?